# How to detect current imbalance?

Tags: ground, current-measurement

I would like a circuit that detects current imbalance between two conductors.  The currents are normally equal and opposite in direction, but can vary in time (or reverse direction).  Neither conductor is very close to ground.

This is pretty similar to GFCI device, except in my case the imbalances of interest are in the microamps, and the current is up to 100 milliamps.  Also, current can spike up or down (while staying balanced) over tens of microseconds.

How do GFCI devices usually work?  Are they based on transformers and relays, or semiconductors?  Would it be possible to modify that circuit to make it more sensitive (and faster)?  Is there a different approach that would work?

Comment: AC? DC? Are the currents going in the same direction?

Comment: @EMFields: AC, opposite directions - sorry, I will add that above.

Comment: Bandwidth of interest? Response time? Amplitude difference to cause trigger?

Comment: @Andyaka: Typical spikes are tens of microseconds long.  ~10MHz would be great, 1MHz should be good.

Comment: Does bandwidth include DC? Responce time? Trigger amplitude?

Comment: @Andyaka: The current can have a DC component.  Response time in tens of milliseconds due to accumulated current imbalance over time is ok; trigger amplitude ideally < 10 microamp average difference (on currents that are 2-5 milliamp average but with 100 milliamp spikes).  Thank you - excellent questions, this is helping me clarify the specs also.

Comment: And, just to be sure, a DC imbalance also causes a trigger and needs to be detected?

Comment: And how much impedance can be tolerated in each line. Also what voltages are present on each line?

Comment: @Andyaka: DC imbalance also causes a trigger, ideally, but being able to trigger outside of spikes is less important in practice - mainly worried about imbalance that occurs during a current spike.  Impedance that can be inserted in the lines is roughly in the kiloohm range (< 100 ohm would be beter).  Voltages are up to 100V to ground and 100V between lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you can put up to 1k ohm in each wire, then it seems like the simplest solution is to insert a pair of current sense resistors, each connected to a 'current sense' differential amplifier that can tolerate the high common mode voltage of the wires.  Then simply subtract the outputs of the current sense amps with another differential amp and then use a window comparator on the output of that.  If you use high precision parts with decent temperature coefficients, I think you can get the accuracy you need.  Note that 10 uA on 100 mA is 0.01 percent, so all of the differential amplifiers will have to be rather carefully designed.  You're going to need at least 80 dB CMRR.

Comment: I had to read all the comments to find the 1k ohm spec.  (1k at 100 mA is a bit much, but 50 or 100 ohms might be nice.)

Comment: He's also going to need .005% resistors, or at least resistors stable to that level. This will imply, at the least, stringent care with thermal layout to avoid temperature differentials.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way is to use a current transformer, Hall effect sensor, or Rogowski coil, and run both leads through the aperture. If the current in one wire is exactly balanced by the current in the other, the sensor should give zero output. Only the imbalanced current will be detected.

Comment: Dc imbalances need to be detected ruling out a transformer unless part of a composite solution.